# ESP32 HTTPS simple GET request

Tags: c++, esp32

I'm trying to improve my project with HTTPS and I want to do a simple HTTPS get request using ESP32 to this test server:

https://pcsvision-a.ddns.net:12347

this is my code

```
#include <HTTPClient.h>
 
const char* ssid = "DSRSB2-1701 2.4Ghz";
const char* password =  "DSR112233";
 
void setup() {
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
 
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
}
 
const char* root_ca= \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
"MIIF1zCCA7+gAwIBAgIUTTXGz/9tVfCXMouYk5WriH8sQUQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\n"
"BQAwezELMAkGA1UEBhMCTVkxETAPBgNVBAgMCFNFTEFOR09SMQ4wDAYDVQQHDAVL\n"
"QVBBUjEiMCAGA1UECgwZTHVtaW5hbmNlIFN5c3RlbXMgU2RuIEJoZDElMCMGCSqG\n" 
"SIb3DQEJARYWaGVsbG9AbHVtaW5hbmNlc3lzLmNvbTAeFw0yMTA3MTEwNzQzNDNa\n"
"Fw0yMjA3MTEwNzQzNDNaMHsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAk1ZMREwDwYDVQQIDAhTRUxBTkdP\n"
"UjEOMAwGA1UEBwwFS0FQQVIxIjAgBgNVBAoMGUx1bWluYW5jZSBTeXN0ZW1zIFNk\n"
"biBCaGQxJTAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWFmhlbGxvQGx1bWluYW5jZXN5cy5jb20wggIi\n"
"MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4ICDwAwggIKAoICAQDLKpuUjDg8u0pitLtS8coz5RFe\n"
"iSr64hCarEX/PlnrvtGe5Hv/FYnupU5hAgCQ46/n3Qf4ZfyImLa058/YSyFs7tEb\n"
"rI7z5Scx+6Nh1O7I9YVf+6A1GPVE6hAmZrIaJ3AP+APuPb+r4wWLtk/RN1a+kKdI\n"
"Jn02MA1FaE5z8Q7QWI0urI8Nq2t/lbj+5BjWxJ+S8lUzkpPV0IfvQOugjjwUcxLC\n"
"9kEvKo7iBfDCjOjpmqFQFHxoon/m7nmrDo8rhHROAjadUGYMZqDdBbB1AwgpJXQp\n"
"UCWJ7JlL+ESdYLru9WZNNLxUH/SyXOkhbmmozNVkgMeP1ktXk+e+hqA1tZGXqh2v\n"
"bqHgukVy7N1NQN165em6wMw7mBANEgHDawtx7s0jPEWu3oo3ADLuPLjK0tMoLnn6\n"
"xPHuaE+Cawh5E67kZz46fwlMffqUVN1i5FN7auiIEtG5n3JcQmLbR8tkE2kxq8Va\n"
"ysbJ+QSzI6kAtXXvDHEfCc5EqmXZ3G13zQEkgqXhiKoj9x7Yhan4TJ/dCx6cSI9k\n"
"Pbg9LyWrtIIsbP8c+FDqxVjnNOMbguYtYiCcYU2oIy6iezMN5G7v7K39cEhY81D5\n"
"TD+SgG2e2EnHFKRUc2sS0FeLy0rLMWERlxAAFkcoawBLXKtIO+bFs9+jKyJ+MYGZ\n"
"/+PPV0zibybi6UcBCQIDAQABo1MwUTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUSzCTsTqtgrnX8G0RsHGG\n"
"F7yPpjMwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUSzCTsTqtgrnX8G0RsHGGF7yPpjMwDwYDVR0TAQH/\n"
"BAUwAwEB/zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEALNgLB86lBj3ZRvzwQTaNm/DVmJW0\n"
"1oCTozRCW2mE1NhAOOkpYjhcighaJZMPxwsBAbuMpz5rbse+vJvilKquxP1fCs/V\n"
"gJkhrdsZuCOzHILXF8PxBo7hoYSp4pncuvXwcnF0ys8UPB655tAkieDWUe2OR0g/\n"
"agPNXU6oMZ0AaSVeoqjY5q5hdpqPmCEuP8DkPZu9KhZoJahKQggi3mKaINf+abT2\n"
"Ni4kKJxRiDMyBY5Xai/8QLT1gubIn6uo2KmBNaBFeOdOPsoWh5qZEGzIr/0S0fYz\n"
"HvAob1rpFX+/Sa3Q5/JrrvW8h0UIggZTtVQRO63TNxDz39Nd3WAa4EeonFygF36U\n"
"BxQPBneFhAoRHP/3D7gvZLoNfp+wOPCkTAdI9E5oN8Ph5qIsVjiOqQqIRD0VioYT\n"
"lILQYq/zfA4aLKr0dQbkl3CloDqVNgDNoQgjb9dBsPyJ9AfcSvls5mWbcHvtBy1U\n"
"Xe27/NF0n8wVUI4gmbN1dxPPjp/fzVxb4sn6kxU3muMW2cvt4urv6xHlMUK2r/iO\n"
"Z6ibzHChoMPaSrRcb8GNYcYjmTJaTaD+wN3ycFJZmiILfeD6LPkO8RvcPUIOA37q\n"
"FOdh33OWUAteb/0iK9q/RXE2wJKldwZ6b2SnaaFi5aGXKEfvPbI4gAnRkDB4TCqr\n"
"M3kcM8AMKKWIRuw=\n"
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
 
void loop() {
 
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { 
 
    HTTPClient http;
 
    http.begin("https://pcsvision-a.ddns.net:12347", root_ca); 
    int httpCode = http.GET();                                                  
 
    if (httpCode > 0) { 
 
        String payload = http.getString();
        Serial.println(httpCode);
        Serial.println(payload);
      }
 
    else {
      Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
    }
 
    http.end(); //Free the resources
  }
 
  delay(3000);
}
```

Im getting this error from the serial monitor

```
Connecting to WiFi..
Connecting to WiFi..
Connecting to WiFi..
Connected to the WiFi network
[E][ssl_client.cpp:36] _handle_error(): [start_ssl_client():216]: (-9984) X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed
[E][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:133] connect(): start_ssl_client: -9984
[W][HTTPClient.cpp:1417] returnError(): error(-1): connection refused
Error on HTTP request
[E][ssl_client.cpp:36] _handle_error(): [start_ssl_client():216]: (-9984) X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed
[E][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:133] connect(): start_ssl_client: -9984
[W][HTTPClient.cpp:1417] returnError(): error(-1): connection refused
Error on HTTP request
[E][ssl_client.cpp:36] _handle_error(): [start_ssl_client():216]: (-9984) X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed
[E][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:133] connect(): start_ssl_client: -9984
[W][HTTPClient.cpp:1417] returnError(): error(-1): connection refused
Error on HTTP request
```

I'm still learning and I really appreciate your help ..

**you dont need to read the next**
I cant post this question witout adding more words at the same time I dont want to waste your time .. I wanted my question to be to the point

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks like there is a problem with that website. Firefox reports "pcsvision-a.ddns.net:12347 uses an invalid security certificate." Maybe the library will not proceed on that condition.

Comment: but can you do it without ESP32? i do not wanna know what is it to be fair. Just use `openssl` stuff

Comment: I think you did your example like this: [https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/11/18/esp32-arduino-https-get-request/](https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/11/18/esp32-arduino-https-get-request/) Does the example code from that page work with your ESP? As far as I understand the example, the ESP is a HTTP-client, and the server shall respond with a certificate. Which shall be checked from the client?!

Comment: Your certificate is wrong - it should have a CommonName matching your site name (CN=pcsvision-a.ddns.net). Then the second parameter of `http.begin` is not a certificate but a string containing the SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code below is from a firmware code I've been programming lately to use on Tensilica's Xtensa LX6/7 compatible MCUs (ESP32). The code below makes an HTTPS GET request to a Dataverse repository ([dataverse.org](https://dataverse.org)) using WIFIClientsecure library.

**Using HTTPClient**

```
 String GetInfoFromDataverse2(String url) {
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    mserial.printStrln("WiFi Disconnected");
    if (connect2WIFInetowrk()){
      GetInfoFromDataverse(url);
    }
  }
  
  mserial.printStrln("URL: " + url);
    
  HTTPClient http;

    http.begin("https://" + SERVER_URL + url, HARVARD_ROOT_CA_RSA_SHA1); //Specify destination for HTTP request
    http.addHeader("Host", SERVER_URL);
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    //http.addHeader("X-Dataverse-key",  API_TOKEN);
    http.addHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json");
    http.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate" );
    http.addHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8" );
    http.addHeader("User-Agent", "AeonLabs LDAD Smart DAQ device" );
    //http.addHeader("Keep-Alive", "300" );
    //http.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive" );
    http.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-us" );
    http.addHeader("Connection", "close" );    
    
    String payload="";
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    mserial.printStrln("");
    mserial.printStrln("HTTP Code: " + String(httpCode));
    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code
        payload = http.getString();
        mserial.printStrln(payload);
    }
      
    return String(payload);
}
```

**Using WIFIclientsecure**

```
String GetInfoFromDataverse(String url) {
  //Check WiFi connection status
    
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    mserial.printStrln("WiFi Disconnected");
    if (connect2WIFInetowrk()){
      GetInfoFromDataverse(url);
    }
  }
            
  int str_len = SERVER_URL.length() + 1; // Length (with one extra character for the null terminator)
  char SERVER_URL_char [str_len];    // Prepare the character array (the buffer) 
  SERVER_URL.toCharArray(SERVER_URL_char, str_len);    // Copy it over 
    
  client.stop();
  client.setCACert(HARVARD_ROOT_CA_RSA_SHA1);
    
  if (!client.connect(SERVER_URL_char, SERVER_PORT)) {
      mserial.printStrln("Cloud server URL connection FAILED!");
      mserial.printStrln(SERVER_URL_char);
      int server_status = client.connected();
      mserial.printStrln("Server status code: " + String(server_status));
      return "";
  }
  
  mserial.printStrln("Connected to the dataverse of Harvard University"); 
  mserial.printStrln("");
  
  // We now create a URI for the request
  mserial.printStr("Requesting URL: ");
  mserial.printStrln(url);

  // Make a HTTP request and add HTTP headers    
  // post header
  String postHeader = "GET " + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  postHeader += "Host: " + SERVER_URL + ":" + String(SERVER_PORT) + "\r\n";
  //postHeader += "X-Dataverse-key: " + API_TOKEN + "\r\n";
  postHeader += "Content-Type: text/json\r\n";
  postHeader += "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json,text/json;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
  postHeader += "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n";
  postHeader += "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n";
  postHeader += "User-Agent: AeonLabs LDAD Smart DAQ device\r\n";
  //postHeader += "Keep-Alive: 300\r\n";
  postHeader += "Accept-Language: en-us\r\n";
  postHeader += "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

  // request tail
  String boundary = "7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";
  String tail = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n\r\n";

  // content length
  int contentLength = tail.length();
  //postHeader += "Content-Length: " + String(contentLength, DEC) + "\n\n";
  
  // send post header
  int postHeader_len=postHeader.length() + 1; 
  char charBuf0[postHeader_len];
  postHeader.toCharArray(charBuf0, postHeader_len);
  client.print(charBuf0);
  
  mserial.printStrln("======= Headers =======");
  mserial.printStrln(charBuf0);
  mserial.printStrln("======= End of Headers =======");
  
  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to mserial
  String responseHeaders = "";

  mserial.printStr("Waiting for server response...");
  long timeout= millis();
  long ttl=millis()-timeout;
  while (client.connected() && abs(ttl) < 30000) { // 30 sec.
    ttl=millis()-timeout;      
    responseHeaders = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (responseHeaders == "\r") {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (abs(ttl) < 10000){
    mserial.printStrln("OK");
  }else{
    mserial.printStrln("timed out.");  
  }
  
  String responseContent = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  client.stop();

  return responseContent;
  }
```